# aligning DNA sequences and marking a SNP

Tags: linux, dna-sequence

I have two fasta files.
Each file contains sequences of short genomic regions in Rat or Mouse with a species-specific known SNP.

```
File_1 :

>Rat_1
GGTGCCTGTGTATTGCCTCTGTCGACTGCCTTACGATGTGACCCGCTTCATGAT
>Rat_2
AAGCGGCCGGTTTCCTTGGCGACGAAGAGCGCGGGAATTTCAGATAGATTGTAATTGCGGCTGC
>Rat_3
GCAGCCATCTCTGCAACAATTGTGACAATGGCTGAGCCTAGCACAGACCCCAACAAAGAT


File_2 :

>Mouse_1
GGTGCCTGTGTATTACCTCTGTCGACTGCCTTACGATGTGACCCGCTTCATGAT
>Mouse_1_2
AAGCGGCCGGTTTCCTTGGCGTCGAAGAGCGCGGGAATTTCAGATAGATTGTAATTGCGGCTGC
>Mouse_1_3
GCAGCCATCTCTGCAACAATTGTGACAATGGTTGAGCCTAGCACAGACCCCAACAAAGAT
```

What I want to do is to find the SNP and extract about 20 bases around it.
Result should look something like below...

```
Resut_file :

>Rat_1
CTGTGTATTGCCTCTGTC
         ^  
>Mouse_1
CTGTGTATTACCTCTGTC
         ^
```

Please, enlight me, programming masters!!!

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a specific programming question, you basically want us to write your program. Plus, we don't even know what an SNP is, that makes it hard to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools for outputing the diff, like `vimdiff`, `diff` etc.

Try to have a look to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059848/vimdiff-how-to-extract-similar-lines-in-files-and-output-them-to-a-file)

P.S. Asking such a question here is not relevant, you have to show at least what you have tried to do.