# How to compare two files containing many long strings then extract lines with at least n consecutive identical chars?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, diff, string-comparison

I have 2 large files each containing long strings separated by newlines in different formats. I need to find similarities and differences between them. The Problem is that the formats of the two files differ.

File a:

```
9217:NjA5MDAxNdaeag0NjE5NTIx.XUwXRQ.gat8MzuGfkj2pWs7z8z-LBFXQaE:dasda97sda9sdadfghgg789hfg87ghf8fgh87
```

File b:

```
NjA5MDAxNdaeag0NjE5NTIx.XUwXRQ.gat8MzuGfkj2pWs7z8z-LBFXQaE
```

So now I want to extract the whole line containing `NjA5MDAxNdaeag0NjE5NTIx.XUwXRQ.gat8MzuGfkj2pWs7z8z-LBFXQaE` from File a to a new file and also delete this line in File a.

I have tried achieving this with meld and got to the point that it will at least show me the similarities only. Say File a has 3000 lines and File b has 120 lines, now I want to find the the lines with at least n consecutive identical chars and remove these from File a.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059848/vimdiff-how-to-extract-similar-lines-in-files-and-output-them-to-a-file) and accordingly tried to use diff like this:

```sh
  diff  --unchanged-line-format='%L' --old-line-format='' \
  --new-line-format='' a.txt b.txt
```

This didn't do anything I got no output whatsoever so I guess it exited with 0 and didn't find anything.

How can I make this work? I have Linux and Windows available.

Comment: So, file `b` contains 120 strings, and you want to remove any line from file `a` that contains any of the 120 strings as substrings?

Comment: thats exactly what im trying yes

Comment: And the file `a` strings are always the same format? ie. `[some text or numbers]:[potential substring from b]:[more text or numbers]`?

Comment: yes precisely this is the case. though one needs to take into account more `:` delimiters might follow
`[8549]:[NjA4NzMyedea212RELEVANTSUBSTRING5zz-JqDtvpAIkZq8oLiX2cBVI]:[irrelevantstring]:[irrelevantstring]:[irrelevantstring]`

Comment: I checked again the additional `:` always follow so the above structure is valid for all entries in the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the format of the files, the most efficient implementation would be something like this:

1. Load all `b` strings into a `[hashtable]` or `[HashSet[string]]`
2. Filter the contents of `a` by:

   - Extracting the substring from each line with `String.Split(':')` or similar
   - Check whether it exists in the set from step 1

```
$FilterStrings = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [string[]]@(
        Get-Content .\path\to\b
    )
)

Get-Content .\path\to\a |Where-Object {
    # Split the line into the prefix, middle, and suffix;
    # Discard the prefix and suffix
    $null,$searchString,$null = $_.Split(":", 3)

    if($FilterStrings.Contains($searchString)){
        # we found a match, write it to the new file
        $searchString |Add-Content .\path\to\matchedStrings.txt

        # make sure it isn't passed through
        $false
    }
    else {
        # substring wasn't found to be in `b`, let's pass it through
        $true
    }
} |Set-Content .\path\to\filteredStrings.txt
```